# UIImagePickerController delegates not calling from a custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsobject

I'm trying to create a PhotoManager class to handle the UIImagePickerController and settings. So I created a NSObject called PhotoManager. To display the UIImagerPickerController, I get a reference to the parentView. The picker displays great but the manager is not getting any delegate calls.

But if I get the parentView as the delegate it does get the delegate calls.

Here is my 'takePhoto' method:

```
-(void) takePhoto{

    //Create the image picker control
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    //set the source to the camera dependant on if a camera is avialable
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }else{
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }

    //set the delegate
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    //show the camera
    [parentVC presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Can a NSObject not get delegate calls from the Picker? Can a delegate get calls if it's being presented in a different object? I'm starting to get very frustrated.

Comment: Have you verified that your `PhotoManager` instance is still around by the time the user is done with the image picker? Show how you make use of your `PhotoManager` instance.

Comment: You are likely not keeping a reference to the PhotoManager and it is getting nil'ed out.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for your help. I should have guess that one.

Answer (score 2):

As a couple commenters pointed out. I had simply not retained a reference to the `Photomanager`. As soon as I kept a reference, it worked.